# Java Download Manager with my own filename definition

Tags: java, download, save

In https://github.com/luugiathuy/Java-Download-Manager I cannot find the variable for setting/changing a filename with my own definition, not filename in server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not immediately provide one. According to [this code from Downloader](https://github.com/luugiathuy/Java-Download-Manager/blob/master/src/com/luugiathuy/apps/downloadmanager/Downloader.java#L86), it uses `URL.getFile` to determine the output file name:

```
// Get the file name from url path
String fileURL = url.getFile();
mFileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
System.out.println("File name: " + mFileName);
```

This field is used at the following particular points in `HttpDownloader`:

- [here](https://github.com/luugiathuy/Java-Download-Manager/blob/master/src/com/luugiathuy/apps/downloadmanager/HttpDownloader.java#L87)

  ```
  HttpDownloadThread aThread = new HttpDownloadThread(1, mURL, mOutputFolder + mFileName, startByte, endByte);
  ```
- and [here](https://github.com/luugiathuy/Java-Download-Manager/blob/master/src/com/luugiathuy/apps/downloadmanager/HttpDownloader.java#L93)

  ```
  aThread = new HttpDownloadThread(i, mURL, mOutputFolder + mFileName, startByte, endByte);
  ```
- and lastly [here](https://github.com/luugiathuy/Java-Download-Manager/blob/master/src/com/luugiathuy/apps/downloadmanager/HttpDownloader.java#L99)

  ```
  HttpDownloadThread aThread = new HttpDownloadThread(1, mURL, mOutputFolder + mFileName, 0, mFileSize);
  ```

---

Why you don't write your own which supports a custom file name? Surely it would be an interesting exercise for you! Maybe you can write one even better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can rename the file.

```
    File file = new File("/isuru.txt");

    if (!file.exists() || file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist: " + file);
        return;
    }

    File newFile = new File("/leann.ini");

    //Rename
    if (file.renameTo(newFile)) {
        System.out.println("File has been renamed.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error renmaing file");
    }
```